# Using Express JS Passport oAuth and Clustering, how can I stop multiple logins?

Tags: express, passport-google-oauth2

I'm building a web server with Express, Passport (Local and Google oAuth), strong-cluster-connect-store and strong-cluster-control.

I have successfully set up for the LocalStrategy cluster session storage. So you don't keep getting asked to log in.

However for the GoogleStrategy it doesn't do the same. Putting logging in, I can see the ClusterStore.set being called, with the logged in details. But then I see additional set calls, with the session and user data removed.

I tried using ClusterStore as the GoogleStrategy store, however they don't seem to be compatible.

Any help or tips/tricks would be great.